# Change the width of a primefaces picklist

Tags: html, css, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to change the width of my picklist instead of having the default width in primefaces.css
I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
<h:body>
    <f:facet name="last">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="default" name="mystyle.css" />
    </f:facet>
    <p:pickList ...>
       ...
    </p:picklist>
</h:body>
```

And in my mystyle.css I've only this:

```
.ui-picklist .ui-picklist-list{
    width:400px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is apparently never being loaded. If you have checked the generated HTML output and/or the HTTP traffic monitor, you should have noticed it. The culprit is the `<f:facet name="last">` which isn't supported by `<h:body>`. It's only supported by `<h:head>` and even then only when PrimeFaces is installed.

This should do:

```
<h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="default" name="mystyle.css" />

    <p:pickList ...>
       ...
    </p:pickList>
</h:body>
```

#### See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css)

Comment: +1 for "See Also", it's quite common see people using `!important`, which should be avoided.